# Google Sheets OnChange Event with GCP Service Account - How to Tell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I'm struggling trying to find information on how to determine whether the service account had triggered the OnChange event.

I have Users as well as a Service Account recording information to a Google Sheet. I can determine the user who made a change to the sheet by the following:

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

But when ran with a Service Account, it returns an empty string. Google's docs indicate that:

> ...Gets information about the current user. If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string.

I don't believe looking at if the User Email is empty would benefit me as this is more of a catch-all for all users that do not have permissions. There is `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();` but that would return the owner of the service account and that won't help without knowing it was automated or not.

Comment: Do you happen to have the spreadsheet in question shared with the Service Account directly or is the Service Account performing changes using a Key/Domain Wide Delegation (in case this is inside a Google Workspace domain)?

Comment: About `whether the service account had triggered the OnChange event.`, in your situation, how does the service account trigger the OnChange event?

Comment: @YancyGodoy

The spreadsheet was created with my account and the service account email is shared with editor access to that spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tanaike It inserts into several cells on a new row. It does register the event change because I can record a static or variable value to a cell in testing, but as soon as I try and utilize `Session.getActiveUser...` it won't return anything.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `It inserts into several cells on a new row.`, in this case, the new row is inserted into the Spreadsheet using Sheets API with the service account by a script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes exactly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, when the script for requesting Sheets API is run, how about giving the email address of the service account? For example, when the script requests Sheets API, how about sending the value including the email of the service account? This can be retrieved by the OnChange event trigger. If you are not required the email, you can remove it from the script by the OnChange trigger. But, if this was not your expected direction, I apologize.